# How does Xamarin.MediaGallery work in PopupPage in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I am using Rg.Plugins.Popup + Xamarin.MediaGallery. However there is one problem that Xamarin.MediaGallery doesn't work if I add in Rg.Plugins.Popup.

```
<popup:PopupPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:popup="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
            xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            ....>
    <popup:PopupPage.Animation>
        <animations:ScaleAnimation PositionIn="Bottom" PositionOut="Bottom" ScaleIn="1.2" ScaleOut="0.8" DurationIn="400" DurationOut="300" EasingIn="SinOut" EasingOut="SinIn" HasBackgroundAnimation="False"/>
    </popup:PopupPage.Animation>
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" Margin="0" Spacing="0">
        <Image Margin="0" x:Name="pickimg">
            <Image.Source>
                <FontImageSource Color="#ddd" Size="22" FontFamily="MaterIcon" Glyph="{x:Static local:FontIconsClass.Camera}"/>
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="pickimg_Tapped" />
        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    </StackLayout>
</popup:PopupPage>

async void pickimg_Tapped(System.Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var result = await MediaGallery.PickAsync(5, MediaFileType.Image, MediaFileType.Video);
    if(result?.Files == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    foreach (var img in result.Files)
    {
        var filename = img.NameWithoutExtension;
    }
    
}
```

This is how I use it. **Please Note: If I add in ContentPage it works fine. It doesn't work so I add it in PopupPage**

**I'm checking on Xamarin iOS, Android I haven't tried yet.**

How can I use Xamarin.MediaGallery inside Rg.Plugins.Popup? Has anyone encountered this problem please help me with the solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you update all the packages/plugins to the latest .

- Xamarin.forms **5.0.0.2244**
- Xamarin.Essentials **1.7.0**
- Rg.Plugins.Popup **2.0.0.14**
- Xamarin.MediaGallery **2.0.0**

I test on `iPhone12/iOS15` simulator , it works fine without any problem .

Comment: Thank you, I have updated to the new version as you instructed, it still doesn't seem to work for some reason. I will try to find out more

Comment: If possible could you provide us a basic, minimal project to test ? You can simply upload it to GitHub and attach the repo link here .